# Standard link for downloading acrobat reader

Tags: acrobat

I want to provide PDF-documentation in my installer-software. The software should check if PDF is present and otherwise provide a link to acrobat reador download location.
Is there any future-safe URL I can use?

Comment: Maybe you need to look for this info in the Acrobat Reader website ?

Answer (score 0):

Our designer suggested using this link:
https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/pdf-reader.html

Hope, it helps someone else also.